One point I don't understand about Rs in ac analysis of jfets

In the circuit in this 1st picture, Rs resistance is bridged with C3 capacitor, so Rs is disabled when analyzing ac.

but in this 2nd picture there is a capacitor bridging the Rs resistor, but we draw it in ac analysis, we do not disable it. what is the logic here? I would be grateful if you explain where I am missing.

In the second picture Rs is not bridged by a capacitor - the capacitor is in series with the output.

The first circuit is "Common source" ... The second is "common drain", or "follower". See where the ouput is ... connected to load.

softcalculate - Hi, Where did the schematics come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then give full details of the source e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY

Because it is not in parallel, so it is not bridging the 2.2k resistor.
The second topology cannot have a bypass capacitor otherwise there wouldn't be any signal at Vo. And the 0.05uF is simply AC coupling the output, can be ignored and shorted for small signal analysis purposes at signal frequencies.

hmm, that is, if the capacitor and resistor are connected in parallel, it is short-circuited. Do I understand you correctly?

@softcalculate it is shorted for AC frequencies, because of how little the capacitor's impedance is at such frequencies. However, you need a suitable value of capacitance to make that assumption.

What you're saying is very open-ended. Isn't there anything clearer about it?

@softcalculate what's open ended about it? I don't understand. Could you explain what's your confusion?

but now, but in your last message, you said that we need the appropriate impedance value to make this inference. here, if we cannot always say that it will be short-circuited when it is parallel. then according to what do we determine the appropriate impedance value?

The first is an AC-coupled common-source amplifier. It has voltage gain and a relatively high output impedance.
The second is an AC-coupled source follower. It has no voltage gain, just current gain, and a relatively low output impedance.
